# XSD error: No matching global declaration available for the validation root

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation, xml-validation

When I try to validate the XML file I am given this error:

> person.xml:3: element person: Schemas validity error : Element `{http://www.namespace.org/person}person`: No matching global declaration available for the validation root.

This is the content of the person.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<p:person xmlns:p="http://www.namespace.org/person">
  <firstName>name</firstName>
  <surName>surname</surName>
  <secondName>n2</secondName>
</p:person>
```

This is the content of the person.xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:p="http://www.namespace.org/person"   
           version="1.0">

    <xs:element name="person">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:group ref="credential"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:group name="credential">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="firstName" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="surName" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="secondName" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:group>     
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates that the namespaced element, `{http://www.namespace.org/person}person`, is not found in the given XSD because the `p` element there is not in the `http://www.namespace.org/person` namespace.  Correct the problem by adding `targetNamespace="http://www.namespace.org/person"` to the `xs:schema` root element of the XSD.  Next, adjust the reference to the `credential` group to also use that namespace.

Altogether, the following XML will be valid against the following XSD:

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<p:person xmlns:p="http://www.namespace.org/person">
  <firstName>name</firstName>
  <surName>surname</surName>
  <secondName>n2</secondName>
</p:person>
```

### XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:p="http://www.namespace.org/person"
  targetNamespace="http://www.namespace.org/person"
  version="1.0">
  
  <xs:element name="person">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:group ref="p:credential"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  
  <xs:group name="credential">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="firstName" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="surName" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="secondName" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:group>  

</xs:schema>
```